# Cloudformation for UsagePlan with Method Throttling

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am new to cloudformation, I am trying to follow the AWS doc to create a Usage Plan with Method throttling. I need to define an [ApiStage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-usageplan-apistage.html#cfn-apigateway-usageplan-apistage-throttle) with Throttle attribute.

I tried below approach but got an error - `Value of property Throttle must be an object with String (or simple type) properties`

```
  ApiUsagePlan:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan"
    Properties:
      Throttle:
        RateLimit: 10
        BurstLimit: 10
      ApiStages:
      - ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
        Stage: !Ref ApiStage
        Throttle: -------> how to define this property?
          RateLimit: 5
          BurstLimit: 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify **path and method** to be throttled. For example:

```
  ApiStages:
    - ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
      Stage: !Ref ApiStage
      Throttle:
        "/helloworld/ANY":
            BurstLimit: 5
            RateLimit: 5
```

Where `/helloworld/ANY` must be replaced by your own path and method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar and associate my throttle configuration to my resource/method.but i got a error on that particular line under Throttle: "myresource/mymethod", just wanted to confirm if this worked for you

Comment: This really saved my day! I have to say that the AWS documentation is really unclear how to setup method-level throttling: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigateway-usageplan-apistage.html